# "Change" is being fired when adding options to select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got two selects and when the first one in changed I'm recreating the second like this:

```
    _selectSubcategory : function (parent_id) {
        this.id('cat_select').find('option').remove().end();
        var option_list = [];
        option_list.push('<option selected value="0"></option>');
        $.each(this._data.categories, function (k, cat) {
            if (cat.parent_id == parent_id) {
                option_list.push('<option value="' + cat.cat_id + '">' + cat.cat_name + '</option>');
            }

        }.bind(this));

        this.id('cat_select').append(option_list.join('\n'));
}
```

And I've got an event listener on 'change' event for this select.

The problem is that this event is being fired every time I call `_selectSubcategory`. How do I fix it?

Comment: The problem is that you are removing the selected item and adding a new one so this code is actually behaving how you should expect. In order to provide an answer, could anything be selected in this `select` before this is triggered?

Comment: @ars265 oh, I see. So... what workaround can I use here?

Comment: Well you could leave the 0 option there and remove the others but if the user is able to select anything previous then it could still trigger. In this case I would handle the events yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment, unless you remove the element that's currently selected it [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/pUyZ7/).

You can either add a condition to exempt `option[selected]` when you re-populate the list, or expect it to fire a change event when you manipulate the entire `<select>`.

You can use `.one` coupled with `.stopPropagation` to ignore a change that's been triggered by reloading the list. Something like:

```
var $select = $('#options');
$('#add').click(function(e){
    var val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
        opt = 'option ' + val;
    $('<option>',{'value':'val','html':opt}).appendTo($select);
});
$('#reset').click(function(e){
    $select.one(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    var newopts = {
        '0': 'Please select one...',
        '1': 'Option 1',
        '2': 'Option 2',
        '3': 'Option 3'
    };
    var $lastOpt = $select.find('option').last(),
        newValue;
    // add the new options first
    $.each(newopts, function(v,k){
        if (!newValue) newValue = v;
        $('<option>',{'value':v,'html':k}).appendTo($select);
    });
    // change index once (.one will catch and suppress the change event)
    $select.val(newValue);
    // remove previous elements
    $lastOpt.add($lastOpt.prevAll()).remove();
});
$('#options').change(function(e){
    $('#debug').append('Change detected.\n');
});
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/pUyZ7/1/

Comment: I believe you mean unless you don't remove the currently selected element, that is what is cause the event to fire.

Comment: Worded differently, it will work without firing a change event _unless_ the selected item is also removed.